# SharePoint 2019 icon formatting issue

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have migrated couple of pages to SP 2019 on-prem and we see the following issues on some pages, any suggestion how can we fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you check if any CSS file is missing? Is there file not found or 404 error in browser developer console for any files?

Comment: I checked the css files, there is no missing file